# Hidden character getting when copied from phonebook and paste in textfield. How to remove it

Tags: ios, swift

I Have mobile number as login id when someone copied number and pasted in textfield. it show me "9999999999\u{e2}". "\u{e2}" is Hidden character which is not display in textfield but when check in logs it showing me. 
I want to remove that type of characters.

Thanks in advance for your kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to trim any none-numeric character

```
let strWithAll = "kdldls155558894"
let number = strWithAll.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
let myString = "dasdf3453453fsdf23455sf.2234"
let result = String(myString.characters.filter { String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")) != nil })
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`\u{e2}` actually indicates `â`. I am not sure why this character is getting copied along with the number but as the special characters are appended at the end of the string, you can try this approach:

```
let yourText = "9999999999\u{e2}"
textField.text =  yourText.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) [0]
```

Check the functionality of components(separatedBy:) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-components

Comment: @Needhi Roy If user enter any string then I need to show alert to enter proper mobile number and if there is hidden character then remove it and process further. so how can I differentiate above two scenarios

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the phone number has only digits (i.e. no "-" or "+" or space characters), you can simply filter out the characters that are not digits:

```
let number = "9999999999\u{e2}"
let filteredNumber = number.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 } // 9999999999
```